# Result missing when indexing xpath query

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

[Xml file here](http://pastebin.com/zMZw2kwG).

The two following loops give different output, despite both doing essentially the same thing:

```
XPathNavigator nav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
foreach (object v in (XPathNodeIterator)nav.Evaluate(@"//*[heads!=1]/name"))
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(v);
}

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{   
    Console.Out.Write(i);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(nav.Evaluate(string.Format("string(//*[heads!=1][{0}]/name)", i)));
}
```

Output:

```
Zaphod
Frankie and Benji
Eddie
1Zaphod
2Frankie and Benji
3
```

Why is "Eddie" missing off the end of the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two XPath expression do not do "essentially the same thing":

According to the [XPath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev):

> The location path `//para[1]` (...) selects all descendant `para` elements that are the first `para` children of their parents.

Analogously, the XPath expression `//*[heads!=1][3]/name` (looking at the 3rd iteration that should yield *Eddie* right away) selects the `name` child of all descendant elements that are "the third children of their parents whose number of heads differs from 1".

i.e. the `3` refers to the set of children that fulfil the indicated number of heads restriction *within their parent node*.

Instead, try: `/descendant::*[heads!=1][{0}]/name`

Comment: So where is `Frankie and Benji` coming from? That's not a second child.

Comment: @RichardLovely: *Frankie and Benji* are the second child in their parent node that doesn't have exactly one head. (And the first child in their parent node whose `name` is *Frankie and Benji*.)

Comment: Ah, I was having trouble groking what your first post said.

An easier fix is to add brackets:

`string((//*[heads!=1])[{0}]/name)`

Comment: @RichardLovely: Indeed, I was having trouble myself explaining what I wanted to say ;-) Right, the brackets seem like another good solution.